# Fourier transform of $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

Tags: normal-distribution, fourier-transform, gaussian

> Fourier transform of
>   $$e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$

I know to use the Fourier transform direct formula however I keep getting an algebraic mess. so if someone could help me out with detailed steps that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Let $F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2 - sx}dx$. For $s \in \mathbb{R}$ you can apply the change of variable $y = x+s$. What do you get ?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\hat{f}(k)=&\int_\mathbb R \exp\left(- \frac 1 2 x^2 - i k x\right) \, dx \\
=& \int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(- \frac 1 2 (x^2 + 2i k x)\right) \, dx \\
=&\int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(- \frac 1 2 (x + i k )^2-\frac 1 2 k^2\right) \, dx \\
=&e^{- \frac 1 2 k^2}\int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(- \frac 1 2 y^2\right) \, dy\\
=&\sqrt{2 \pi}e^{- \frac 1 2 k^2}
\end{align}

You possibly defined the Fourier transform as a the product of this with $2 \pi$ or $\sqrt{2 \pi}$.
You can think of the fourth equality sign as substituting $y=x+ik$. This is justified by using contour integration in the complex plane using a rectangular path with one path along the reals, $2$ vertical paths at infinity parallel to the imaginary axis and a path in negative direction along $\mathbb R +ik$.